# Pidgin show panel icon in Ubuntu 18.4 GNOME 3.2

Tags: ubuntu-gnome, gnome-panel, pidgin

Ubuntu 18.4 GNOME 3.2
When I click on Pidgin messenger icon it runs in background. But is no any indicators to see it connected or not, what is my current status.. Some solution to add icon into panel like for last Skype?